# How to initialize FileWriter outside of the main() method

Tags: java, apache-spark, streaming

I am writting a program in Java using the Spark Streaming framework (even if you don't know what Spark is you may still know the answer to my problem ). 
I am basically receiving strings, one per second, through a socket and want to save them in a txt file ( each string separated by a paragraph. So something like this :

```
FileWriter a = new Filewriter (path to file);
a.append(string s);
a.append('\n');
a.flush;
```

The way Spark Streaming works is by converting the main () method into a  big while loop, so in order for me to save the strings I receive in the same file, I need to declare the a variable outside of the main () (otherwise it will keep initializing and saving only the last string it receives ).

The problem is, because of an IOEXCEPTION, I have to do this:

```
public static void writer () throws IOException 
{
   FileWriter a= new Filewriter  (path to file );
}
```

But if I call writer() in the main () I get the same problem as before ( I keep initializing a).

How can I initialize a outside the main (), so I don't have this problem?

Thank you so much.

Comment: why cant you have it flush its contents to a file at the end of the while (main) loop and append to the file each time? But I think the private is the way to go just trying to think of something different.

Comment: can't you call `writer()` in a static block? like `static { writer(); }` ? that way it'll execute only once, upon the including the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare it as a field, however you need to catch the exception in the constructor.  You can do this

```
private final PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(filename, true);
```

Using PrintWriter has the advantage that

- it places an appropriate newline at the end of each line.
- it can be enabled to autoflush.

You can call it with

```
writer.println(text);
```

Comment: Thank you Peter. Now I get a NullPointerException when I try to append my strings, but I guess that is different issue

Comment: @manuelmourato that would happen if you try to append before this code had been called. You can do `println(null)`

Comment: Hmm, if that is the case that it isn't working for me. When you  say 'filename' you mean the path to my existing CSV file correct? I cannot do writer (filepath,true), it doesnt accept it

Comment: Also when I do println(null) in the main () method , it says the command is ambiguous

Comment: @manuelmourato Good point. You need to cast it. You can do `println((Object) null)`

Comment: @manuelmourato This is the constructor I meant https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter-java.io.OutputStream-boolean-

Comment: What I am doing is I'm declaring the private final PrintWriter writer just like you wrote above outside the main

Comment: In the PrintWriter  writer = new PrintWriter  () I write the path to my file 'C:/...'

Comment: And then I go to the main () method and write writer.append (text)

Comment: Should I do something else?

Comment: @manuelmourato That should be enough.  In fact I was wrong that you needed to catch IOException.  This shouldn't have compiled as it wasn't actually being thrown.  Try the simpler example.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts Peter. Now I get a FilenotfoundException, and I am certain that the file name I wrote exists, as well as the directory